# jQuery listener for a server update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on an web app that communicates with a server to update it's database. Problem is the update can take anywhere from a few milliseconds to even tens of seconds at a time with a big update. I would like to introduce some listener on the client side that would wait for server to finish it's last job and inform the client to force a refresh (by refresh I mean calling an ajax function that asks server for new data, destroys present data table and grows a new one).
Until now I just called the refresh on the client side with some delay after making any changes to the server database, but I'd prefer to "grey out" the table on the client side, until it gets a response from the server.

I am a newbie in the jQuery area, can someone point me to how I could achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just make an AJAX call using [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), and then hook into the deferred [`done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) function. That way, when your DB update is done, you can handle everything inside the `done()` function.

For example:

```
$.ajax({  
    'type': 'get',
    'url': 'update_db.php'
}).done(function() {  
    // The PHP has executed and the call has returned.
    // 'Ungrey' your items here...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can poll regurlarly the server for updates:

```
var job = $.Deferred();
var POLL_INTERVAL_MSEC = 5000;
var timer = setInterval( function() {
   $.ajax('status/isfinshed').done( function( response ) {
        if ( response.finished ) {
            clearInterval( timer );
            job.resolve();
        }
   });
} , POLL_INTERVAL_MSEC);

job.done( function() {
    //success code
});
```